# Does Appium for iOS apps need the source code of the app?

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I need to know when setting up Appium with Xcode for testing iOS native application, both on a real device and simulator, if somewhere in the configuration the source code of the app will be needed, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appium has great documentation on their [site](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/platform-support/index.html) which I'll summarize here:

Simulator:

- A simulator build (.app)

Real device:

- A signed .ipa or source code to build one

Comment: I see, but that is not the case with Android apps, which can be directly downloaded as .apk files and automated with Appium.
So what is the correct way to sign the .ipa/.app that I have Without using the source code of the app?